# Ng-Repeat inside the bootbox message

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootbox

I am using bootbox for displaying the multiple data from my controller. I'm going to display the data using ng-repeat in the table using bootbox message. Is that possible? I do some research, but its not working like $compile. This is my code.

```
adminFactory.getOTDetails(id).then(function(results){
$scope.ot_details = results.data;

  bootbox.dialog({
    message: '<fieldset><div align="center"><h5><strong>Over Time Request for Approval</strong></h5></div>' +
        '<table class="table"><tr><td rowspan="3">Name</td><td colspan="2">From</td><td colspan="2">To</td><td rowspan="2">Purpose</td><td rowspan="2">Action</td></tr>' +
        '<tr></tr><td>Date</td><td>Time</td><td>Date</td><td>Time</td></tr></table>' +
        '<tr ng-repeat="app in ot_details"><td>{{ app.name }}</td><td>{{ app.fdate}}</td><td>{{ app.ftime}}</td><td>{{ app.tdate}}</td><td>{{ app.ttime}}</td><td>{{ app.purpose}}</td></tr>' +
        '</fieldset>',
    title: "HRIS+",
    buttons: {
        aprv: {
        label: "Approve",
        className: "btn btn-primary",
        callback: function() {
            return true;
        }
      },
      disaprv: {
        label: "Disapprove",
        className: "btn btn-primary",
        callback: function() {
            return true;
        }
      }
    }
    });
```

Comment: In HTML, ng-repeat works fine, but inside the bootbox message its not working. How can I fix that? Any answer will be appreciated. Thank you Proffesionals!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use angular directives outside the angular environment, here you trying to use `ngRepeat` in BootBox message options which won't recognize angular directives. You need to compile the html string into an html element with a scope bind on it, then pass this element into BootBox:

```
var templateString = '<fieldset><div align="center"><h5><strong>Over Time Request for Approval</strong></h5></div>' +
    '<table class="table"><tr><td rowspan="3">Name</td><td colspan="2">From</td><td colspan="2">To</td><td rowspan="2">Purpose</td><td rowspan="2">Action</td></tr>' +
    '<tr></tr><td>Date</td><td>Time</td><td>Date</td><td>Time</td></tr></table>' +
    '<tr ng-repeat="app in ot_details"><td>{{ app.name }}</td><td>{{ app.fdate}}</td><td>{{ app.ftime}}</td><td>{{ app.tdate}}</td><td>{{ app.ttime}}</td><td>{{ app.purpose}}</td></tr>' +
    '</fieldset>';

var element = $compile(templateString)($scope);

bootbox({
    message: element,

    ...

})
```